# Find k nearest neighbor in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Gets from a set of points only points that are h-neighbors for a point with integer coordinates x and y.
"point" Given point with integer coordinates x and y.
"h" Distance around a given point.
"points" A given set of points.

class Point:

```
public readonly struct Point : System.IEquatable<Point>
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }


    public int X { get; }

    public int Y { get; }
    
    public static bool operator ==(Point left, Point right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }
    
    public static bool operator !=(Point left, Point right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X.GetHashCode() ^ this.Y.GetHashCode();
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(obj is Point))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Point point = (Point)obj;
        
        return this.Equals(point);
    }
    public bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y;
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public static Point[] GetNeighbors(Point point, int h, params Point[] points)
    {
      
    }
```

I don’t know how to solve this problem, I tried to solve it using:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= points.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            PointsCoordinate[i] = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(points[i].X, 2) + Math.Pow(points[i].Y, 2));
        }
```

After that I will find nearest values of point using list or et cetera , but in this case I have to return exactly nearest points from array not values  , how can I solve this , mb I have the wrong approach to solving this problem.
I need to connect sorted values with Points in array, help me please

Comment: Can you explain the procedure in English ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to calculate the distance from your source "point" to each of your neighbor points. You can do that by using [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

[image]

> The sum of the areas of the two squares on the legs (a and b) equals the area of the square on the hypotenuse.

```
public static double CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(Point originPoint, Point destinationPoint)
{
    return Math.Pow(originPoint.X - destinationPoint.X, 2)
        + Math.Pow(originPoint.Y - destinationPoint.Y, 2);
}
```

You can calculate the distance for each of the points using LINQ extension method `Select()`:

```
var pointsWithDistance = points
    .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) });
```

Then filter out the neighbors that are outside the "h" distance with `Where()`:

```
var filteredPointsWithDistance = points
    .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) })
    .Where(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance <= Math.Pow(h, 2));
```

...and order them by growing distance:

```
var orderedFilteredPointsWithDistance = points
    .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) })
    .Where(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance <= Math.Pow(h, 2))
    .OrderBy(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance);
```

The calculated distance is no longer needed, bring back the `Point`, use `Select()` again:

```
var points = points
    .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) })
    .Where(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance <= Math.Pow(h, 2))
    .OrderBy(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance)
    .Select(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Point);
```

Finally, create an array from the resulted sequence of points:

```
return points
    .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) })
    .Where(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance <= Math.Pow(h, 2))
    .OrderBy(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance)
    .Select(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Point)
    .ToArray();
```

The whole code and usage example:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var h = 10;
        var sourcePoint = new Point(0, 0);
        var neighbors = new Point[]
        {
            new Point(0, 0),
            new Point(100, 100),
            new Point(10, 0),
            new Point(5, 5),
            new Point(-2, -2),
        };
        var nearestNeighbors = GetNeighbors(sourcePoint, h, neighbors);
    }

    public static Point[] GetNeighbors(Point point, int h, params Point[] points)
    {
        return points
            .Select(p => new { Point = p, Distance = CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(point, p) })
            .Where(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance <= Math.Pow(h, 2))
            .OrderBy(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Distance)
            .Select(pointAndDistance => pointAndDistance.Point)
            .ToArray();
    }

    public static double CalculateDistanceBetweenPoints(Point originPoint, Point destinationPoint)
    {
        return Math.Pow(originPoint.X - destinationPoint.X, 2)
            + Math.Pow(originPoint.Y - destinationPoint.Y, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this works except for `.Distance <= h`, either square `h` or take the square-root of `.Distance`

Comment: Man, this feels like the joke: “Here’s the answer: <some long Linq query you don’t understand>”